# Where should I put "exec this when jobs 1 .. n are done?"

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic

I have some parallel code and a thread pool.

I dispatch groups of jobs to be completed, and I need to dispatch 15 jobs say, and **when all 15 are complete**, this special job "job 16" should execute.

You can't just enqueue "job 16" last and have the thread pool "exec when ready" because it may start exec of "job 16" *before* jobs 13, 14, 15 are done.

*So*, you need to have a way to count.  My question is, *where does the responsibility* belong?

- **In the calling code**: Use a static/global variable that gets incremented at the end of each job. Jobs 1-15 do `counter++`. When `counter == 15`, exec job 16
- **In the thread pool**:  Add functionality to the threadpool to execute "when no jobs submitted *before it* (timestamp) remain"
- **In the callback**: (responsibility to check that jobs 1-15 are done, spin/sleep otherwise)

Comment: Note that `counter++` is **not threadsafe**. You could use an [`AtomicInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) and call it's [`incrementAndGet()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also consider encapsulation this behaviour in its own class, and raise an event when your jobs are completed to trigger queuing your 16th task e.g.:

```
internal class ParallelBatchRunner
{
    public event EventHandler Completed = delegate { };

    public void Run(List<Action> tasks)
    {
        int count = tasks.Count;

        tasks.ForEach(t =>
        {
            Action completionTask = () =>
            {
                t();

                if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref count) == 0)
                {
                    Completed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            };

            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => completionTask());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this.  Each `ParallelBatchRunner` has a counter, and when the counter reaches batch size and last job in batch is done, an function `BatchReady()` is called that starts the next batch.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the 1st approach.

Beside the approach to count, you can use array of ManualResetEvent[] to synchronize 16th job with 15 jobs remaining.